# How to create predicted probability plot?

Tags: r, regression, glm, multinomial

Using the `debt` data set from the package `faraway`. So basically firstly I was asked to create a model using `multinom` function and use `ccarduse` as the response and `prodebt` as the single covariate. Then I had to create a plot of predicted probabilities of belonging to each credit card use category against `prodebt` score.

```
mod1 <- multinom(ccarduse ~ prodebt, debt)

inclevels <- 0:464
debt$ccarduse <- as.factor(debt$ccarduse)
debt$prodebt <- as.factor(debt$prodebt)

preds <- predict(mod1, data.frame(income=inclevels), type="probs")
# Warning message:
#   'newdata' had 465 rows but variables found have 464 rows
```

Plot of predicted probabilities of belonging to each credit card use category against prodebt score

```
plot(inclevels, preds[, 1], type="l", ylim=c(.15, .6), xlab="prodebt", 
     ylab="Probabilities of credit card use", cex.lab=1.3, cex.axis=1.3)
lines(inclevels, preds[, 2], lty=2)
lines(inclevels, preds[, 3], lty=3)
legend(x="topright", c("1", "2", "3"), lty=c(3, 2, 1), cex=1.5)
```

As seen I got a warning message and the plot looks really creepy. Is there anything I did wrong or I could fix to make it look neat.

[image]

Comment: You predict on `income` but that wasn't used in the model. Did you post the right model?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that `income` was not used in the model (or you posted the wrong code?). Apart from that your code actually looks fine for me, and the plot nice. See example using a variable that's actually in the model:

```
## load data
data('debt', package='faraway')

## calc model
mod1 <- nnet::multinom(ccarduse ~ prodebt, debt)

## predict
prodebtlv <- 1:6
pred <- predict(mod1, data.frame(prodebt=prodebtlv), type="probs")

## plot
plot(prodebtlv, pred[, 1], type="l", ylim=range(pred), 
     xlab="prodebt", ylab="Probabilities of credit card use", 
     cex.lab=1.3, cex.axis=1.3)
lines(prodebtlv, pred[, 2], lty=2)
lines(prodebtlv, pred[, 3], lty=3)
legend(x = "topright", c("1", "2", "3"), lty=c(3, 2, 1))
```

[image]